# What's the best way to handle an old question where the correct answer has changed?

Tags: discussion

A long time ago I asked [this question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/15438/what-happens-if-a-creature-has-no-toughness-defined). With a recent Magic rules update, the correct answer has changed. Sometimes when this happens, the person who answered in the first place will update their answer to include the new information. In this case, someone else made a new answer that's the correct one. Should I change which answer is accepted to the new one?

Answer (score 3):

According to a [few](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183900/is-changing-my-accepted-answer-appropriate-if-the-answer-changes-over-time) [Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251007/should-accepted-answers-change-over-time) [questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188228/external-factor-changed-invalidating-correct-answer) it is up to you (obviously), but it is considered acceptable to change the accepted answer if another one is more correct, or helps you more.

Some other things they mention doing include keeping the currently accepted answer and adding a bounty for the now correct answer, or adding a comment to the answer asking if they want to update their answer so that it is correct.